# Application is crashing with Ogre::ItemIdentityException

Tags: c++, ogre

I am new to OGRE and i am trying to create a 3D line using following tutorial: http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/Line+3D
and application is crashing with following exception Ogre::ItemIdentityException.

Comment: That error happens when you create two Entities (or other Ogre things) with the same name. (cit from : http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=63196)

Comment: i renamed everything in my example but still problem persists.

Comment: More details please. Where exactly is the application crashing?